# What size wire for a 100 amp sub panel 20 feet away

Tags: electrical, wiring

What type and size wire do I need to run to a 100 amp sub panel about 20 feet away I know it will be a 4 wire but that’s it.

Comment: What is the main service feed ampacity?

Comment: 200 amp main service at the meter which is where I would run off of.

Comment: Thank you. There is a special rule when a subpanel feed is equal to the main feed, but that does not apply here.

Comment: How much load do you actually want to put in the sub-panel? It's perfectly legal to feed a panel rated for "X" amps with a breaker smaller than "X" (and corresponding smaller wire). The rating is a *maximum*, not a level you're required to achieve. You may not have load-calculation capacity for an extra 100A, 90A wire can be significantly less expensive than 100A wire, etc.

Comment: Wait, "at the meter which is where I would run off of" meaning this isn't actually a *sub*panel?

Comment: I would treat it as a sub panel ran off of a 100 amp breaker from the main panel ran through conduit underground to my metal shop 20 feet away where I would set up a separate panel with its own integrated shut off. I would also install ground rods off the sub panel.

Answer (score 2):

The basic answer is to go to an [ampacity chart](https://www.cerrowire.com/products/resources/tables-calculators/ampacity-charts/). There are typically three relevant numbers:

- 60 C for copper NM cable (indoors only) or UF cable: *not even an option according to the linked chart*
- 75 C for copper SE cable or wires in conduit: 3 AWG hots & neutral, 8 AWG ground
- 75 C for aluminum SE cable or wires in conduit: 1 AWG hots & neutral, 6 AWG ground

Note that the ground sizes are based on my understanding of [NEC 250.122](https://up.codes/viewer/new_york/nfpa-70-2017/chapter/2/wiring-and-protection#250.122). But common 4-wire SE cables include a larger 4th wire. My understanding is that is because SE is used as a feeder where the wires are hot/hot/neutral (3 wire) or hot/hot/hot/neutral (4 wire), so if you get a 4 wire to use as hot/hot/neutral/ground you end up with a larger ground than you really need, and possibly a larger neutral as well, but that's OK.

Remember that your feed breaker size and wire size do *not* have to match the capacity of the subpanel. If the subpanel is rated at 100A, *or even 200A*, that's OK with a 60A feed (or whatever). A subpanel in another building needs a disconnect, in the same building it does not. But a subpanel anywhere *can* use a main breaker (i.e., really be a "main" panel with a main breaker, as long as neutral and ground are kept separate) as a disconnect.

A **Load Calculation** is critical to determine the amount of power available for your subpanel. With a 200A feed, if your existing loads on your main panel are > 100A then you can't set up your subpanel to use 100A. You really need two load calculations - existing load without the subpanel and load for just the subpanel. There are a lot of things that can be done to solve the overall load problem, if it turns out to be a problem.

Comment: I will go back and get two reasonable calculations. The house and the shop.